# Loop Nested Json for Specific Values

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have a nested Json data from a REST API. I have a foreach loop that tries to get all the "paper" data but for some reason it is not working. How to get all data and display in a table?

The foreach method I created, tries to loop through all the "paper" data and echo the values of all the paper data. When I run this loop I get the error

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'paper' on line 8

**This is the json code:**

```
{
    "status":true,
    "message":"",
    "errors":[

    ],
    "paper":[
        {
            "id":"646473",
            "paperId":"2758110",
            "paperNumber":"2961517831"
        },
        {
            "id":"6536363",
            "paperId":"6376363",
            "paperNumber":"6373774733"
        }
    ]
}
```

**My foreach loop**

```
<?php

 $url = '....';
 $data = file_get_contents($url);
 $characters = json_decode($data, true);

 foreach ($characters as $character) {
     echo 'Online: '. $character['paper'][0]['paperNumber'];
 }
```

**Expected Results**

```
PaperNumber: 2961517831

PaperNumber: 6373774733
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your loop will currently operate on each item in the JSON, so it will first look at `status`, then `message`.  As these items are simple strings, you get the error

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'paper' on line 8

Instead you need to loop over the items `paper` as a start point rather than trying to extract them later (using `$characters['paper']`)...

```
foreach ($characters['paper'] as $character) {
    echo 'Online: '. $character['paperNumber'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nigel. This easy and clean.

Comment: Hello @Nigel How do I return the sum of paperID.